# Atan2 Faster Approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, approximation-theory

I am using atan2(y, x) for finding the polar angle from the x-axis and a vector which contains the point (x,y) for converting Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. But, in my program which will be used for calculations to move a robot, atan2 is a very computationally expensive procedure. What are ways to approximate atan2's result with a fast calculation with error bounds of 1 degree.

Wikipedia reference for atan2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Here is some sample output:

atan2(1, 0)     -->  pi/2
atan2(-1, 0)    -->  -pi/2
atan2(0, 1)     -->  0
atan2(0, -1)    -->  pi

Comment: Table lookup? Used to be an old CS story about a helicopter simulation that took forever until the author realised that the evaluations were on a small lattice, and a table lookup removed that bottleneck. (Bentley's Programming Pearls, I think.)

Comment: I was thinking about doing using a look up table with a limited amount of entries (memory space is used) and then use interpolation to improve accuracy.

Comment: Are the arguments from some regular set of points or can they take any values? How expensive is atan2 compared with *,/, $\sin$, $\cos$?

Comment: Do you think a truncated taylor series is a good idea.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. Without knowing more I would say no, unless you are evaluating most points close to some fixed points. Also, it would need to be a Taylor series for a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you have other questions of this form, you may be interested in [scicomp.se] site.

Answer (score 18):

The pseudo code below computes `r = atan2 (y,x)` in radians. Using IEEE-754 single precision for all variables, the maximum relative error observed for 100 million trials was $6.14(10^{-4})$, thus complying with the requirement that the relative error be $\lt \frac{1}{360} \approx 2.77(10^{-3})$.

The algorithm does not deal with special cases such as $x=0, y=0$, nor does it consider special IEEE-754 floating-point operands such as infinities and NaN.

This is based on a simple argument reduction using the identities $arctan (z) = \frac{\pi}{2} - arctan (\frac{1}{z})$ if $z \gt 0$ and $arctan (-z) = -arctan(z)$ followed by a polynomial minimax approximation on $[0,1]$, with final result mapped back to $[-\pi,\pi]$ based on the octant of the original vector. The polynomial is evaluated using the Horner scheme. The minimax approximation was computed using the [Remez algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

```
a := min (|x|, |y|) / max (|x|, |y|)
s := a * a
r := ((-0.0464964749 * s + 0.15931422) * s - 0.327622764) * s * a + a
if |y| > |x| then r := 1.57079637 - r
if x < 0 then r := 3.14159274 - r
if y < 0 then r := -r
```

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I'm curious why you evaluate a polynomial on $z^2$ rather than $z$, and why is there a $*a + a$ term at the end?

Comment: I think I get it, it's a polynomial in a, so it's 7th order.

Comment: Tried to implement it on a computer. It has a problem with floating point. for x = -21, y = -0.0 (negative floating point), the maximum error is 2pi

Comment: The algorithm you provide is very well from the aspect of optimizations (because it has only three comparisons). But x = -21, y = -0.0 is not a special case,  a point with these coordinates can really exist. The problem is that the algorithm returns -pi, instead of pi. I tried to rewrite it to keep the three comparisons, but to no avail.

Comment: @Bogi: By *definition*, any case that is not handled correctly by a general algorithm *is* a special case. Negative zero is a *common* special case in numerical computation. In order to handle y=(-0.0) correctly, you could replace `if y < 0 then r := -r` with `r = r * copysign (1, y)`. See my example C code at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/85vThqc48).

Comment: Thank you. I took a different path, because I am vectorizing the code.

Comment: I got the aligned imlementation as in std::atan2 with the following changes:
if (max|x|, |y| == 0.0) then a = 0.0 else ...
if ( reinterpret_as_int32(x) < 0) instead of (x < 0), helps with the case where x = -0.0
if (reinterpret_as_int32(y) < 0) instead of (y < 0).
Thank you again.

Comment: @Bogi `copysign()` is easily vectorized as it is simple bit-level manipulation of the sign bit of floating-point data. Using the re-interpretation you chose will also work, or `signbit()`: `if (signbit (y)) r = -r;` I did not include such discussions here, as this is the Math stack and not Stackoverflow, and mathematically there is no such thing as a negative zero, it's purely a floating-point arithmetic thing.

Answer (score 8):

Denote
$$
\operatorname{atan2}(y,x) = \arctan z, \quad \mbox{where} \quad z = \dfrac{y}{x}.
$$

Note that (in degrees) if $z>1$, then
$$
\arctan z = 90^\circ - \arctan \dfrac{1}{z},
$$
and that
$$
\arctan(-z) = -\arctan ~ z.
$$

So, it is enough to write approximation for $z\in [0,1]$.

This simple approximation
$$
\arctan z \approx z\Bigl(45^\circ - 15.66^\circ(z-1)\Bigr)\tag{1}
$$
gives us error $\pm0.22^\circ$.

---

This [source](http://nghiaho.com/?p=997) gives us not bad approximation.
I just translated it to degrees:

$$
\arctan z \approx z\Bigl(45^\circ- \bigl(z - 1\bigr)\bigl(14^\circ + 3.83^\circ z\bigr)\Bigr), \qquad 0\le z \le 1;\tag{2}
$$
error is $\pm 0.09^\circ$.

Authors of the paper said that this formula is $3\times$ faster than standard one.

Comment: Thank this is very useful. But, I am going to leave your answer unaccepted just to see if any more answers come about. If they don't I will mark your answer as accepted in a little while.

Comment: One caveat with this approach is that it doesn't handle the entire circle (you loose information when you compute $z = {x \over y}$).

Comment: atan2(y, x) != atan2(-y, -x), but z = y/x == -y/-x.

Answer (score 1):

The code is intended for Visual Studio and is based on my proposed fast approximation of the arctangent using the Padé-Chebyshev method (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537957/fast-accurate-atan-arctan-approximation-algorithm). Unlike the standard atan2 function, situations where both operands are equal to $0$ or the value $x^2+y^2$ causes an overflow (including when $x$ or $y$ are equal to infinity) are not supported. But this made it possible to achieve fairly high performance and accuracy (~4 ulps max) over a wide range of operands. The function calculates $2\operatorname{arctg} t$, where $$t=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}, \text{ if } x\ge0;$$ and $$t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{y}, \text{ if } x\le 0.$$ Calculations will be even easier if the norm of the vector (x, y) is known in advance.

```
_declspec(naked) float _vectorcall arctg2(float y, float x)
{
  static const float ct[14] =       // Constants table
  {
    6.28740248E-17f,                // a0*(a1+b0)=a0*c1
    9.73632411E-17f,                // 2*a0*a1
    2.24874633E-18f,                // a0*(a3+b2)=a0*c3
    8.04359889E-19f,                // 2*a0*a3
    4.25772129E-17f,                // a0
    8.51544258E-17f,                // 2*a0
    2.50182216E-17f,                // a0*(a2+b1)=a0*c2
    2.51512438E-17f,                // 2*a0*a2
    0.141592654f,                   // pi-3
    3.0f,                           // 3
    0.0f,                           // 0
    -0.141592654f,                  // -(pi-3)
    -3.0f,                          // -3
    3.95889818E15f                  // Threshold value of t^2 when arctg(t)=pi/2*sgn(t)
  };
  _asm
  {
    vmulss xmm2,xmm1,xmm1           // xmm2 = x^2
    mov edx,offset ct               // edx - address of the constants table
    vfmadd231ss xmm2,xmm0,xmm0      // xmm2 = x^2+y^2
    vsqrtss xmm2,xmm2,xmm2          // xmm2 = (x^2+y^2)^0,5
    vucomiss xmm1,[edx+40]          // Compare x with 0
    jnb arctg_x_sgn                 // Goto if x>=0
    vsubss xmm2,xmm2,xmm1           // xmm2 = (x^2+y^2)^0,5-x
    vdivss xmm0,xmm2,xmm0           // xmm0 = ((x^2+y^2)^0,5-x)/y = t
    jmp arctg_x_done                // Continue at the common part of the function
      arctg_x_sgn:                  // Calculation of t for the case x>=0
    vaddss xmm2,xmm2,xmm1           // xmm2 = (x^2+y^2)^0,5+x
    vdivss xmm0,xmm0,xmm2           // xmm0 = y/((x^2+y^2)^0,5+x) = t
      arctg_x_done:                 // xmm0 = t
    vshufps xmm1,xmm0,xmm0,0        // xmm1 = t # t : t # t
    vmovups xmm3,[edx+16]           // xmm3 = 2*a0*a2 # a0*c2 : 2*a0 # a0
    vmulps xmm2,xmm1,xmm1           // xmm2 = t^2 # t^2 : t^2 # t^2
    vmulps xmm4,xmm2,xmm2           // xmm4 = s^2 # s^2 : s^2 # s^2
    jb arctg_big                    // Goto if |t|>1
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx]     // xmm3 ~ 2*(a3*s+a2) # c3*s+c2 : 2*(a1*s+1) # c1*s+1
    vmovhlps xmm1,xmm1,xmm3         // xmm1 ~ 2*(a3*s+a2) # c3*s+c2
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm1      // xmm3 ~ 2*(a3*s^3+a2*s^2+a1*s+1) # c3*s^3+c2*s^2+c1*s+1
    vmovshdup xmm2,xmm3             // xmm2 = 2*P; xmm3 = Q
    vdivss xmm2,xmm2,xmm3           // xmm2 = 2*P/Q
    vmulss xmm0,xmm0,xmm2           // xmm0 = 2*t*P/Q = 2*arctg(t)
    ret                             // Return
      arctg_big:                    // For |t|>1 use the formula pi*sgn(t)-2*arctg(1/t)
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx]     // xmm3 ~ 2*(a2*s+a3) # c2*s+c3 : 2*(s+a1) # s+c1
    vmovmskpd eax,xmm1              // If t<0 then eax=3 else eax=0
    vmovhlps xmm0,xmm0,xmm3         // xmm0 ~ 2*(a2*s+a3) # c2*s+c3
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm0      // xmm3 ~ 2*(s^3+a1*s^2+a2*s+a3) # s^3+c1*s^2+c2*s+c3
    vmovss xmm0,[edx+4*eax+32]      // xmm0 = (pi-3)*sgn(t)
    vucomiss xmm2,[edx+52]          // Compare s=t^2 and threshold value
    jnb arctg_end                   // If |t|>=62919776, the required data is already in xmm0
    vmovshdup xmm4,xmm3             // xmm4 = 2*P; xmm3 = Q
    vmulss xmm1,xmm1,xmm3           // xmm1 = x*Q
    vfmsub132ss xmm0,xmm4,xmm1      // xmm0 = (pi-3)*|t|*Q-2*P
    vdivss xmm0,xmm0,xmm1           // xmm0 = (pi-3)*sgn(t)-2*P/(x*Q)
      arctg_end:                    // Add to result 3*sgn(x)
    vaddss xmm0,xmm0,[edx+4*eax+36] // xmm0 = pi*sgn(t)-2*P/(x*Q) = 2*arctg(t)
    ret                             // Return
  }
}
```

Below is the code for a similar function that returns the angle in degrees. The function arctgD (arctangent in degrees) used here is given in the link at the beginning of the post.

```
_declspec(naked) float _vectorcall arctg2D(float y, float x) // atan2 in degrees
{
  static const float ct[3] =        // Constants table
  {
    -0.0f,                          // -0
    180.0f,                         // 180
    -180.0f                         // -180
  };
  _asm
  {
    vmovmskps ecx,xmm0              // ecx=1 if y<=0; ecx=0 if y>=0
    vmovmskps eax,xmm1              // eax=1 if x<=0; eax=0 if x>=0
    vdivss xmm0,xmm0,xmm1           // xmm0 = y/x - prepare the argument of arctangent
    bts ecx,eax                     // ecx=2 or ecx=3 if x<=0; ecx=1 if x>=0
    call arctgD                     // Calculate arctangent in degrees of y/x
    vaddss xmm0,xmm0,[offset ct-4+4*ecx] // Add or subtract 180 if necessary
    ret                             // Return
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use MathJax https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation