# Complex natural logarithms by hand

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I would like to calculate complex natural logarithms to at least 2 decimal places. I read that in $\mathbb{R}$,

$\ln(x) \approx 1024\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}}}}}}}} - 1\right)$

My question is: ***Is there a similar approximation that could be used for an arbitrary complex natural logarithms?*** Acceptable operations would include addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, square roots, and the natural logarithm over $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $\ln(1+i\sqrt2)$.

P.S. If any other (trig) functions are a must, is there an approximation for them that satisfies the above conditions?

Comment: Umm, complex numbers can be represented in polar coordinates as $x+iy = re^{i\theta}$, so $\log(x+iy) = \log(re^{i\theta}) = \ln r + i\theta$ with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$

Comment: $$\arctan x = x-\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}-\dfrac{x^7}{7}\pm \cdots$$ and so you just need to determine a number of terms to get "pretty close".

Comment: Or how about even easier: $$-1\le x \le 1\Longrightarrow \left|\dfrac{\pi}{4}x+x(|x|-1)(0.2447+0.0663|x|) - \arctan x \right| < 0.0015$$ Of course this only works for a small subset of such problems.

Comment: I found several more algorithms for $\arctan$ [here](http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Documents/EfficientApproximationArctgFunction.pdf)

Comment: Note that $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{x^r-1}{r}=\ln x.$$ In your question $r=1/1024$, so yes, it's pretty close. The closer $r$ is to $0$, the better the approximation.

Comment: Just apply your formula: $$\ln(z)=\ln|z|+i\text{arg}(z).$$

Comment: As $x$ gets large the approximation gets terrible.  $\ln x$ eventually grows more slowly than $x^\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.  For example, at $x=10^{1024}, (x^{1/1024}-1)*1024=9216, \log x \approx 2358$

Comment: Check out 
[logarithm-in-terms-of-a-biased-harmonic-geometric-mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151974/logarithm-in-terms-of-a-biased-harmonic-geometric-mean).

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\i{\mathbf{i}}\def\csgn{\operatorname{csgn}}$
Approximation of $z=\ln(x)$ for $x=1+\i\sqrt2$,
using the iterative process, described in [logarithm-in-terms-of-a-biased-harmonic-geometric-mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151974/logarithm-in-terms-of-a-biased-harmonic-geometric-mean)

\begin{align}
a_0&=1
,\quad b_0=\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}
\approx 1.11111111111111-0.314269680527354 \i
.
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\hline
             & a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n} & b_{n+1}=\frac{2a_{n+1}b_n}{a_{n+1}+b_n}  \\
\hline
 0 & 1                                       &   1.11111111111111-0.314269680527354\,\i \\
 1 & 1.06438048870936-0.147630327622986\,\i &   1.09264520100549-0.226330269351991\,\i \\
 2 & 1.07903316534205-0.186374758729136\,\i &   1.08610682343404-0.206051211450446\,\i \\
 3 & 1.08260204288905-0.196175035358333\,\i &   1.08437057357007-0.201094169303908\,\i \\
 4 & 1.08348830398453-0.198632229129848\,\i &   1.08393043846677-0.199862012932458\,\i \\
 5 & 1.08370949584702-0.199246972686134\,\i &   1.08382002949588-0.199554418641696\,\i \\
 6 & 1.08376477045852-0.199400686392044\,\i &   1.08379240387118-0.199477547881011\,\i \\
 7 & 1.08377858765151-0.199439116557030\,\i &   1.08378549600469-0.199458331929273\,\i \\
 8 & 1.08378204185852-0.199448724206933\,\i &   1.08378376894681-0.199453528049994\,\i \\
 9 & 1.08378290540456-0.199451126126200\,\i &   1.08378333717664-0.199452327086965\,\i \\
10 & 1.08378312129072-0.199451726606441\,\i &   1.08378322923374-0.199452026846632\,\i \\
11 & 1.08378317526224-0.199451876726528\,\i &   1.08378320224799-0.199451951786576\,\i \\
12 & 1.08378318875511-0.199451914256551\,\i &   1.08378319550155-0.199451933021563\,\i \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

\begin{align} 
\ln(x)&\approx \tfrac12\,(x-\tfrac1x)\,b_{12}
=0.549306150980934+0.955316618159709\,\i
\end{align}

All operations can be done over $\mathbb{R}$,
including
the square root of the complex number $u+v\,\i$,
\begin{align} 
\sqrt{u+v\,\i}&=
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{2\,\sqrt(u^2+v^2)+2\,u}
+\tfrac12\,\i\,\csgn(v-u\,\i)\,\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{u^2+v^2}-2\,u}
,
\end{align}

where 
\begin{align}
\csgn(u+v\,\i)&=
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1,\quad \text{if }u>0 \text{ or } u=0 \text{ and } v>0,\\
-1,\quad \text{if }u<0 \text{ or } u=0 \text{ and } v<0
\end{cases}
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a complex number $a + bi$ can be converted to $re^{i\theta}$ form.

$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

$\theta = \arg(y, x)$

Wait a minute! We need an approximation for [arg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29)   also known as [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

To follow the rules, I will include one suggested here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105038/

> $u = \frac{\min(\mid x\mid, \mid y\mid)} {\max(\mid x\mid, \mid y\mid)}$
>
> $w = -0.0464964749u^7 + 0.15931422u^5 - 0.327622764u^3 + u$
>
> If $\mid y\mid \gt \mid x\mid$, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - w$
>
> If $x \lt 0$, $\theta = \pi - w$
>
> If $y \lt 0$, $\theta = -w$

Let $ln$ be the natural logarithm over the reals, approximated in the question, and $v$ be the natural logarithm of $a + bi$, aka $re^{i\theta}$

$v = \ln r + i\theta$

Answer (score 0):

If you need a good approximation
$$-1\le x \le 1\Longrightarrow \left|\frac{63 x\left(\frac{64 }{945}x^4+\frac{7 }{9}x^2+1\right)}{15 x^4+70 x^2+63}- \arctan( x) \right| < 0.00019$$